# Property 'contactId' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to filter an array of abject called 'notes'. When I try this, I get the error: Property 'contactId' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

```js
notes: Array < any > [] = [];
currentNotes: Array < any > [] = [];

notes.forEach(element => {
  //Filter out notes without contact  
  if (element.contactId != null) {
    this.currentNotes.push(element);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define array of arrays, your code should looks like that

```
   notes: Array < any > = [];
    currentNotes: Array < any > = [];

    notes.forEach(element => {
      //Filter out notes without contact  
      if (element.contactId) {
        this.currentNotes.push(element);
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

just check `element`  contains contactid or not before comparing

```
notes: Array < any > [] = [];
    currentNotes: Array < any > [] = [];

    notes.forEach(element => {
      //Filter out notes without contact  
      if (element.contactId&&element.contactId != null) {
        this.currentNotes.push(element);
      }
    })
```